# Jackson databind dependency error on Spring Boot, AWS application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jackson, dependency-management

I created a Spring Boot application from start.spring.io, with Web dependency. I then added AWS SDK dependency as -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.157</version>
</dependency>
```

On builing the application, I am getting the following error -

```
2017-07-02 03:02:11.431  WARN 18412 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageConverters' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters]: Factory method 'messageConverters' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module
```

where

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module
```

is occurring several times in the error log.

I checked tree and dependency hierarchy etc, but if I exclude Jackson from AWS dependency, the same error is still occurring.
How to resolve this error?

Here is the pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample1</groupId>
    <artifactId>Sample13</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Sample13</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.106</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.157</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are excluding Jackson from both from AWS Dependency and Spring Boot nor are you defining it yourself as a dependency.

Why exclude jackson it is required.

Without excluding Jackson from Spring Boot the App starts,

concrete example - https://github.com/Flaw101/jackson-databind-error

Comment: No, I am not excluding from both AWS, Boot at the same time, but only from one of them. I added Jackson separately too. So, I tried all possibiities.

Comment: @DevS I don't see the separate inclusion anywhere.

Comment: @DevS No where is Jackson defined as a separate dependency within your example.

Comment: I have edited the post and pasted the original pom. I was trying these exclusions, separate inclusions etc (which I happened to post) and nothing worked.

Comment: @DevS something else must be causing this. Updated my gitrepo with your current POM and the application still starts. I'd also call out your BOM import is currently useless as you are using the fat jar with every AWS SDK piece in it rather than pulling modules you need which would be backed by the BOM.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe application starts but it gives the error when AWS client is being built with credentials..I guess

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and After removing below dependency solve my problem. 
Remove dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.157</version>
</dependency>
```

Its perfectly working for me.